# My HDD memory is fuller every day

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive

I have a weird problem with Windows 7. It started about 14 months ago. I had 10 GB free space on C on maximum 146 GB. D was okay. Tomorrow, 8 GB free! Next day, 6 GB free until 250 KB free. I cleaned up space somehow and got 3 GB free. Now everyday I have lower and lower free memory. I disabled Windows Update. I think do games write on the disk. I play only LOTR: The Return Of the King. Antivirus is Bitdefender the latest, installed a few days ago. How can I stop filling my hard disk? Programs Files on C is 20 GB but on D 40 GB. I think Windows is filling my HDD with cache and other junk files. How to resolve this?

Comment: 10GB isn't a whole lot of space nowadays. You should consider freeing up more space by default to ensure future system stability

Comment: Presumably it only uses 2GB on particularly "heavy" days? In 14 months you could have potentially used 840GB+ of "unknown"?! Do you reboot daily? I would wager that 2GB (per day) is more than simply "Windows caching".

Answer (score 1):

D is typically your recovery partition and C is where your drive will save any and all of your what can be considered normal data (games, temporary files, cache, etc etc)

Disk clean up is a great tool, but you may find a tool called CCleaner to be much more effective. You can download it for free and it has much more in depth options than a Disk Cleanup.

[CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download)

Is there anything not being used you can get rid of to create space?

Also, as you continue to fill the drive, you may notice (or not) a decrease in your drive performance.

Answer (score 1):

[CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) alongside [CCenhancer](http://singularlabs.com/software/ccenhancer/) may help you reclaim some of that lost space.

Answer (score 1):

please download the program [TreeSizeFree](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/) and run it (as admin to see all data). It shows you which folders use all the space.

[image: TreeSizefree]

Are you able to locate the folder which uses most space?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Windows uses C: drive as default for all temporary files, browser cache and so on.
Have you tried to use standard "Disk Cleanup" tool?

> Open Disk Cleanup by clicking the Start button . In the search box,
>   type Disk Cleanup, and then, in the list of results, click Disk
>   Cleanup.
>
> In the Drives list, click the hard disk drive that you want to clean
>   up, and then click OK.
>
> In the Disk Cleanup dialog box, on the Disk Cleanup tab, select the
>   check boxes for the file types that you want to delete, and then click
>   OK.
>
> In the message that appears, click Delete files.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen with Windows 7 Professional...you might have Windows Backup set to the backup destination D:.
Start>All Programs>Maintenance>Backup and Restore